# How to retain row height and column span attribute after sorting on QTableWidget?

Tags: qt, qtablewidget

I just realize that in QTableWidget, if I modify a row height or change its column span, after sorting, that information is not tied to sorted data. It ties only to that physical row index. Well, this is understandable as user is actually sorting the data, hence the data got sorted.

But surely we also love to make the attribute of that row tied to the data. How do we accomplish this (easily)? Do QTableWidget has this ability built-in?

Comment: I guess I will have to add this size/span attributes on my custom QTableWidgetItem class. Haven't done this, but will report it here when I have accomplish it